How to create a PointVector for the screen corners in React Native Fast OpenCV?
I am using React Native Vision Camera and React Native Fast OpenCV. I have successfully obtained a PointVector with the corner points of a document found in an image captured by the Vision Camera.
Now I want to create another PointVector that represents the four corners of the phone's screen or the original image (for example, (0,0), (width,0), (width,height), (0,height)). I want to use this new PointVector in the getPerspectiveTransform function, but I can't figure out how to create it.
I've checked the documentation for React Native Fast OpenCV but haven't found a solution. Is there any way to achieve this?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
That's how my function for detecting contours and drawing edges looks:
  const testContours = () => {
    const image = OpenCV.base64ToMat(capturedImage!.base64);
    let output_image = OpenCV.createObject(
      ObjectType.Mat,
      frameDimensions.value!.height,
      frameDimensions.value!.width,
      DataTypes.CV_8U
    );
    let kernel = OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Size, 5, 5);

    OpenCV.invoke(
      'cvtColor',
      image,
      output_image,
      ColorConversionCodes.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
    );

    OpenCV.invoke(
      'threshold',
      output_image,
      output_image,
      165,
      250,
      ThresholdTypes.THRESH_BINARY
    );
    OpenCV.invoke('GaussianBlur', output_image, output_image, kernel, 0);

    const contours = OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.MatVector);
    OpenCV.invoke(
      'findContours',
      output_image,
      contours,
      RetrievalModes.RETR_TREE,
      ContourApproximationModes.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    );

    const contours_mat = OpenCV.toJSValue(contours);

    let largest_contour_area = 0;
    let largest_contour: PointVector | undefined;

    for (let i = 0; i < contours_mat.array.length; i++) {
      const contour = OpenCV.copyObjectFromVector(contours, i);
      const hull = OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Mat, 0, 0, DataTypes.CV_8U);
      OpenCV.invoke('convexHull', contour, hull);

      const epsilon = OpenCV.invoke('arcLength', hull, true);
      const approx = OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.PointVector);
      OpenCV.invoke('approxPolyDP', hull, approx, 0.02 * epsilon.value, true);

      const { value: area } = OpenCV.invoke('contourArea', approx, false);

      if (area > largest_contour_area) {
        largest_contour_area = area;
        largest_contour = approx;
      }
    }

    if (largest_contour) {
      let n_points = OpenCV.toJSValue(largest_contour).array.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < n_points - 1; i++) {
        OpenCV.invoke(
          'line',
          image,
          OpenCV.copyObjectFromVector(largest_contour, i),
          OpenCV.copyObjectFromVector(largest_contour, i + 1),
          OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Scalar, 0, 255, 0),
          3,
          LineTypes.FILLED
        );
      }

      OpenCV.invoke(
        'line',
        image,
        OpenCV.copyObjectFromVector(largest_contour, n_points - 1),
        OpenCV.copyObjectFromVector(largest_contour, 0),
        OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Scalar, 0, 255, 0),
        3,
        LineTypes.FILLED
      );

      OpenCV.invoke('rotate', image, image, RotateFlags.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);

      setSavedImage(OpenCV.toJSValue(image).base64);
    }

    OpenCV.clearBuffers();
  };

After rotation I'd like to create a matrix for perspective transform and then apply transformation using that matrix.
React Native Vision Camera version: 4.5.3
React Native Fast OpenCV version: 0.3.2

got a link to the documentation?

Sure, here you have: https://lukaszkurantdev.github.io/react-native-fast-opencv

incomplete/inconvenient API. "invoke"... wow. -- file a bug report/feature request. -- docs suggest they want you to create the empty object first, then call methods on it.

Yep, that's what I've been doing so far. According to the docs, it seems that PointVector cannot be initialized with any values. I was hoping to find a method or function to assign Point objects to a PointVector directly, and I was hoping someone had already figured it out. It seems I might need to find another approach.

there is some explanation in the react-native-fast-opencv repository how to use getPerspectiveTransform. Please check an example below:
const matrixPtr = OpenCV.invoke(
    'getPerspectiveTransform',
    OpenCV.createObject(
    ObjectType.Point2fVector,
    points.value.map(p =>
        OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Point2f, p.x, p.y),
    ),
    ),
    OpenCV.createObject(
    ObjectType.Point2fVector,
    [
        {x: 0, y: 0},
        {x: warpedWidth, y: 0},
        {x: warpedWidth, y: warpedHeight},
        {x: 0, y: warpedHeight},
    ].map(p => OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Point2f, p.x, p.y)),
    ),
    DecompTypes.DECOMP_LU,
);
const destPtr = OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Mat, 0, 0, DataTypes.CV_8U);
OpenCV.invoke(
    'warpPerspective',
    srcPtr,
    destPtr,
    matrixPtr,
    OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Size, warpedWidth, warpedHeight),
    InterpolationFlags.INTER_LINEAR,
    BorderTypes.BORDER_CONSTANT,
    OpenCV.createObject(ObjectType.Scalar, 0),
);

Source: https://github.com/lukaszkurantdev/react-native-fast-opencv/issues/13#issuecomment-2395165024
I hope it will be helpful for you.
